# How to properly return an array from a function that gets a list of elements from a Firebase database with Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I defined the following function to get a list of zipcodes from a Firebase database in a class called Zipcodes

```
// Return an array of Zipcodes from the Firebase database
    func getZipcodesArray(array: [String]) -> [String] {
        var zipcodes = array
        _ZIPCODE_REF.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.childrenCount) // I got the expected number of items
            let enumerator = snapshot.children
            while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FDataSnapshot {
                print("Zipcode: \(rest.value.stringValue)")
                zipcodes.append(rest.value.stringValue)
            }
        })
        return zipcodes.sort()
    }
```

However, when I try to use the returned array as follows:

```
var arr = [String]()
var zipcodes = Zipcode.service.getZipcodesArray(arr).copy()
```

I get the following error:

**Instance member 'arr' cannot be used on type ViewController**

Zipcode.swift code:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class Zipcode {
    static let service = Zipcode()

    private var _BASE_REF = Firebase(url: "\(BASE_URL)")
    private var _ZIPCODE_REF = Firebase(url: "\(BASE_URL)/zipcode")

    var zipcodes = [String]()

    var BASE_REF: Firebase {
        return _BASE_REF
    }

    var USER_REF: Firebase {
        return _ZIPCODE_REF

    }

    // Return an array of Zipcodes from the Firebase database
    func getZipcodesArray() -> [String] {
        _ZIPCODE_REF.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.childrenCount) // I got the expected number of items
            let enumerator = snapshot.children
            while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FDataSnapshot {
                print("Zipcode: \(rest.value.stringValue)")
                self.zipcodes.append(rest.value.stringValue)
            }
        })
        return zipcodes.sort()
    }
}
```

**UPDATE: added completion handler to the function**
How do I return the array?

```
// Return an array of Zipcodes from the Firebase database
func getZipcodesArray(completionHandler: ([String]) -> Void) {
    _ZIPCODE_REF.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot.childrenCount) // I got the expected number of items
        let enumerator = snapshot.children
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FDataSnapshot {
            print("Zipcode: \(rest.value.stringValue)")
            self.zipcodes.append(rest.value.stringValue)
        }
    })
    completionHandler(self.zipcodes)
}
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of Zipcode.service?

Comment: Your method will never return anything because `observeSingleEventOfType` works asynchronously and returns the snapshot in the completion block after the method has exited

Comment: could you offer an alternate solution?

Comment: You need a completion block. There are a lot of examples here on SO even for `observeSingleEventOfType`.

Comment: Could you please help me update the function? I did the following but I have not been able to find an example to have the completion handler return an array. Please see my UPDATE above.

Comment: The call of the completion handler must be **inside** the *observe..* block after the `while` loop.